# Error adding scale bar with map.scale

Tags: maps, scale, r-maptools

I manage to create a map and even include a north arrow, but can't get the `map.scale` to work and getting this kind of error:

> Error in map.scale(x = -83, y = 12, ratio = FALSE, relwidth = 0.2, cex
>   = 0.6) :    unused arguments (ratio = FALSE, relwidth = 0.2, cex = 0.6)

Here is the code:

```
    library(maps)
    library(mapdata)  
    library(ggmap)
    library(mapproj)
    library(maptools)  #for shapefiles
    library(scales)  #for transparency
    library(GISTools)
    range <- readShapePoly("isthmanianpacificmoistforestecoregion") #layer      of data for species range
    map("worldHires", c('Cost', 'pan', 'Nic', 'Colombia'),    xlim=c(-89,-75),ylim=c(5,13), col="lightgray", fill=TRUE) #plot the region I want
    map.scale(-81,8,relwidth = 0.15, metric = TRUE, ratio = TRUE)
    plot(range, add=TRUE, xlim=c(-89,-75),ylim=c(5,13), col=alpha("green", 0.6), border=TRUE)  
    map.scale(x=-80, y=10) #, relwidth=0.3, cex=0.5, ratio=FALSE) 
    north.arrow(xb=-77, yb=12, len=0.2, lab="N", col="black", fill=TRUE) #
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `map.scale()` is a function for both `maps` and `GISTools` packages. You are trying to use the function from the `maps` package. Since you are loading first `maps` and then `GISTools`, the `map.scale()` from `maps` is being masked (probably R throws a warning when loading the last package).

The solution is to specify the package in the function call:

```
maps::map.scale(-81,8,relwidth = 0.15, metric = TRUE, ratio = TRUE)
```

Also why two calls to `map.scale`? You should probably exclude one of them.